# PowerShell : Is it mandatory to save script module in same name as directory

Tags: powershell

In regarding to Modules, [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module?view=powershell-7) mentions its preferable

> Save a PowerShell script with a .psm1 extension. Use the same name for the script and the directory where the script is saved.
>
> To install and run your module, save the module to one of the appropriate PowerShell paths, and use Import-Module.

PowerShell paths -> located in the `$env:PSModulePath`

I haven't followed them and saved Script Module `chart_gui.psm1` in one of a local folder and I could still `Import-Module` and call functions in it but `Remove-Module` is throwing error.

```
Import-Module 'H:\path_x\chart_gui.psm1'
#Call the function
$selectedCharts = selectCharts     
Remove-Module 'H:\path_x\chart_gui.psm1'
```

my Error:

```
Remove-Module : No modules were removed. Verify that the specification of modules to remove is correct and those modules exist in the runspace.
```

my `$env:PSModulePath`

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> $env:PSModulePath
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\Windo
wsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Remove-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-module) isn't designed to accept *file paths* in order to identify the module to be removed.

Instead, use one of the following methods:

```
# By simple name.
# If your module is just a stand-alone *.psm1 file, the module name
# is the base name of that file (the file name without extension).
Remove-Module -Name chart_gui  # -Name is optional

# Example of a fully qualified module name, which assumes a module 
# that has a manifest file (*.psd1).
# Again, the base name of that file is implicitly the module name, and,
# typically, modules with *.psd1 files are placed in folders of the same
# name.
# Use the values specific to your module.
# To eliminate all ambiguity, you can also add a 'Guid' key with the GUID
# from your manifest.
Remove-Module -FullyQualifiedName @{ ModuleName = 'chart_gui'; RequiredVersion = '1.0.0' }

# By PSModuleInfo object, as reported by Get-Module or Import-Module -PassThru
Get-Module -Name chart_gui | Remove-Module  # -Name is optional
```

- Typically, only *one* module with a given name is loaded in a session, but it is possible to load multiple ones side by side.
  That's when you need the `-FullyQualifiedName` parameter (which both [`Get-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module) and `Remove-Module` support) in order to disambiguate.
- A simple way to avoid ambiguity is to use `-PassThru` when you call `Import-Module` (with an explicit path), which outputs a [`System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo) instance describing the module, which you can later pass to `Remove-Module`.

```
# Load (import) the module; -PassThru passes the
# imported module through as a PSModuleInfo object, which you can later pass
# to Remove-Module.
$module = Import-Module -PassThru 'H:\path_x\chart_gui.psm1'

# ... work with the module

# Unload it again.
$module | Remove-Module
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not still be the appropriate way but Ican avoid error by using

```
Remove-Module 'chart_gui'
```